# is there any way of getting the same effect as grouping several things in css with a background color without using a div

Tags: css

so my html looks like this:

```html
<div class="claim approved">
 <div class="claim_left"> 
   <div class="claim_number">1235</div> 
   <div class="claim_date">2004-02-09</div> 
   <div class="claim_policy">23423342323</div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="claim_center"> 
   <div class="claim_type">Loss of goods</div> 
   <div class="claim_description">Lost my luggage</div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="claim_right"> 
   <div class="payout_amount">$600</div> 
   <div class="claim_status">approved</div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

and my css looks like this:

```css
.claim { display:flex; margin-bottom:8px; padding:8px; border-radius:8px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; gap: 10px; } 
.claim_left { background-color:lightgray; text-align: center; margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:-10px; padding:8px; margin-left: -10px; width:100px; } 
.claim_center { flex-grow:1 } 
.claim_right { width:100px; color:white; padding:8px; text-align:center; margin-top:-8px; margin-bottom:-8px; margin-right:-8px; } 
.claim_type { font-weight: bold; } 
.Approved .claim_right { background-color:green; } 
.Declined .claim_right { background-color: red; } 
.Pending .claim_right { background-color:brown; } 
.claim.Approved { background-color: lightgreen; } 
.claim.Declined { background-color: pink; } 
.claim.Pending { background-color: yellow; }
```

ie - I sort of have a pill with three sections in it - with multiple items vertically in each section, sort of like a table.

this works, but the claim_left, claim_center, and claim_right elements purely exist to enforce some sort of structure...  I'd prefer to complete divorce the data from the styling.  Is there any way to get exactly the same result without those three divs? ie all structure comes from css?    If I absolutely position everything within the .claim , I can layout elements where I need them to - but still can't get the background colours right -  I tried a few things, like using :before elements, but I just couldn't get it working.

Comment: Could you show us the HTML rather than some pre processed version?

Comment: I don't understand the question - that is the html?   obviously vue at runtime produces multiple claims, and replaces everything in between {{}} with raw text

Comment: The question is whether you could show us the actual HTML. What you have shown us is not HTML. You can find the actual HTML in your browser's devtools inspect facility and copy it into your question.

Comment: have changed it so it's actually html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove those three elements and instead format using a 3 column 3 row grid.

```css
.claim {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.claim {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-areas: 'number type amount' 'date description status' 'policy . status';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.claim>* {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  rdisplay: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.claim_number,
.claim_type,
.payout_amount {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.claim_policy {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.claim_number,
.claim_date,
.claim_policy {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}

.claim_number {
  grid-area: number;
}

.claim_date {
  font-weight: bold;
  grid-area: date;
}

.claim_policy {
  grid-area: policy;
}

.claim_type {
  grid-area: type;
}

.claim_description {
  grid-area: description;
}

.payout_amount {
  grid-area: amount;
}

.claim_status {
  grid-area: status;
}

.payout_amount,
.claim_status {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.approved .payout_amount,
.approved .claim_status {
  background-color: green;
}

.declined .payout_amount,
.declined .claim_status {
  background-color: red;
}

.pending .payout_amount,
.pending .claim_status {
  background-color: brown;
}

.claim.approved {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.claim.declined {
  background-color: pink;
}

.claim.pending {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="claim approved">
  <div class="claim_number">1235</div>
  <div class="claim_date">2004-02-09</div>
  <div class="claim_policy">23423342323</div>
  <div class="claim_type">Loss of goods</div>
  <div class="claim_description">Lost my luggage</div>
  <div class="payout_amount">$600</div>
  <div class="claim_status">approved</div>
</div>
```

Note, I have made all classes lower case as CSS is case sensitive.